# I need to be notified if a condition fails in my database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a database with Tables and Stored Procedures( with lots of sql statements). 
Once a week the Windows Task scheduler pulls data from a different source and saves it in a Database table B. I need to compare Table B with existing Table A and if the quantity of Table B is less than Table A, i need to be notified through Email or any other such process.

How can i do that? Please help me. I could nt get any information from the Net

Comment: hmmm, you wanna do this with code? what code have you written?

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough to really answer it. I've given it a shot, but I fall short without details. If you're writing code, then you need to show us the code you're writing. If you're a SysAdmin, you need to get your developers to come up with a solution for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the answers. Based on an answer i was told that i was not clear. So i will add few more points. Firstly, I created a Dts Package, then Job(Step 1 has the DTS Package; Step 2 created a Database Email Notification to let users know if the job ran successfully) and scheduled it to run once a week. Every thing works fine. Now i was asked a request to either notify or stop the JOb if the table B < Table A rows. I dont know where and what to write the code...In Stored Procedure or Job Alerts etc

Answer (score 1):

You can create a sql job, and send mail in sql like this

```
if (Select COUNT(*) from A) != (select COUNT(*) from B)
begin
EXEC master.dbo.xp_sendmail 
    @recipients=N'x@x.com;y@x.com',
     @message=N'Tables count different',
     @subject=N'SQL Tables' ;
End
```

before send mail in sql you must set sql main and give permissin by

```
sp_configure 'SQL Mail XPs', 1;
```

Comment: I really recommend AGAINST xp_sendmail. SQL Mail XPs are deprecated, you should be using database mail instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the answers. Based on an answer i was told that i was not clear. So i will add few more points. Firstly, I created a Dts Package, then Job(Step 1 has the DTS Package; Step 2 created a Database Email Notification to let users know if the job ran successfully) and scheduled it to run once a week. Every thing works fine. Now i was asked a request to either notify or stop the JOb if the table B < Table A rows. I dont know where and what to write the code...In Stored Procedure or Job Alerts etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally write a .NET console app and run it as a scheduled task. The app will query the database and processes the results. If it passes, notify of the pass, if it fails, notify of the failure.